# Updating data from AWS DynamoDB to MongoDB Compass

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a SpringBoot application that uses AWS DynamoDB. I added a separate MongoDB profile that I want to use locally.

How do I bring the data from DynamoDB to MongoDBCompass and update it every time DynamoDB changes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB changes can be taken from DynamoDB Streams (Change Data Capture) and you can use a Lambda trigger to consume the changes and update your MongoDB accordingly.

1. [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)
2. [Lambda Consumer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)
3. [MongoDB and Lambda](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/serverless-development-lambda-atlas/)